# How to join related data in a RESTful Web API?

Tags: angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api

This seems like a common situation so I've been searching for a question like this but I can't find it.  I have built a RESTful Web API in ASP.NET.  I have two related tables: Photos and PhotoGroups.  The Photos table has a PhotoGroupID column that relates to the same column in PhotoGroups.  In my AngularJS Single Page Application I have retrieved data from both tables using the standard RESTful queries.  I am displaying a page with the Photos listed in a grid layout and one of the columns is the PhotoGroupID, numbers like 1, 2, 3, and 4.  So how can I display the names of those groups instead of those numbers by joining the two queries in a RESTful fashion?  I know how to add a new method in the Web API that gives me that joined data, but that doesn't seem natural in a RESTful sense.  What is the common way to do this on the client side in AngularJS?  Is there some kind of filter that joins the two tables, or some special syntax to bind a column to the PhotoGroup name column?  I'm going to run into many cases like that when displaying information from related tables in the future and I want to do this the right way.

Comment: Could you not add a List<Photos> property to the PhotoGroups. Then when you open/look at a photogroup, it pulls down all the photos inside that group? You would then have access to the group information as well as all the photos inside that group.

Comment: My take is that you have the API handle the relationship between Photos and PhotoGroups and avoid the second call to the API.  If you're concerned about handling updates that may negatively impact either table then I would implement a DTO with appropriate mapping that excludes either entity from an update.  I don't think any of that violates the spirit of a restful api.

Comment: There is a good pluralsight video on the topic: https://wildermuth.com/2015/07/22/Mapping_Between_Entities_and_View_Models

Comment: Dylan, I've done what you suggested, but what if I want to show all photos and see their group names?  That's going to be a common situation in a lot of tables.  jbrown - It sounds like you're saying create a method on the Web API that returns the joined data.  That's my next move if someone doesn't have a better suggestion.  Steve Greene - I started to watch the video, but it's beyond my skill level.  I'd have to learn about Auto-mapping first, and I don't have time today.

Comment: @SteveGaines - yes, you understood my comment correctly.  Start with returning the joined entities in one api call but I would strongly recommend eventually learning how to implement DTOs and Automapper as described in the video Steve Greene linked to.  But you can take it one step at a time and work up to that.  That's how I started out.

Answer (score 0):

I started to solve this problem by adding a new method to my Web API that joined the Photos and PhotoGroups tables, but I quickly realized that I would be returning a collection of anonymous objects.  To resolve that would require declaring a new class that contained the columns I wanted to return.  That seems like it's getting much more complicated than the beauty and simplicity of REST.

So I pondered the alternatives in AngularJS and decided that I could write a custom filter that would convert the PhotoGroupID into a GroupName using the PhotoGroups JSON array that I already had in the controller scope.  The code that implemented that solution is shown below.  It's a little messy, but not very and it keeps the Web API nice and simple.

```js
in Filter.js:

angular.module('PhotoFilters', []).filter('groupName', function ()
{
    return function (input, scope)
    {
        var groupName = "Not Found";
        angular.forEach(scope.PhotoGroups, function (group)
        {
            if (group.PhotoGroupID == input)
            {
                groupName = group.GroupName;
            }
        });
        return groupName;
    };
});

in my HTML table:

<td>{{ x.PhotoGroupID | groupName:this }}</td>
```